# Text vertically aligned is not formatted properly straight away only after hovering in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am adding elements to a HTML table using jQuery like this:

```js
var tr = '<tr class="row">' +
    '<td><p class="vertical-text">hello</p></td>' +
    '<td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200" /></td>' +
    '</tr>';

$('#tableX').append(tr);
```

```css
.vertical-text {
    padding-right: 5px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
}

#tableX tr.row:hover {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

table {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableX" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>image</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When opening the HTML file the vertical-text is not aligned properly straight away, but when hovering the row it changes its style how it is supposed to look.
When omitting the `#tableX tr.row:hover` rule it works fine!

Here is an expanded example: https://jsfiddle.net/2cdpf28s/2/

**EDIT**

I figured out this is only a bug in Safari and it only occurs when using `:hover` any ideas?

Comment: you have a quote within your `<td>` tag

Comment: You could add a `table { table-layout: fixed; }` to your css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with this snippet. There is an unwanted quote `"` in td  here `'<tr> <td">`.

Secondly you need to add a `#` to the selector in this case to refer to the ID of a DOM element (`tableX` in `$('tableX').append(tr);`).

```js
var tr = '<tr> <td><p class="vertical-text">' + "test" + '</p></td> </tr>';
$('#tableX').append(tr);
```

```css
.vertical-text {
  padding-right: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tableX' align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I corrected it, I omitted some unnecessary code for an easier understanding. I have uploaded a better more detailed version, sorry for this inconvenience!

Comment: I added a jsfiddle as well for clarification, could you have a look at it please and update / delete your answer?

Comment: Oh I think it is only like that in Safari @brk